# ? Rotation Retention CSS | JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm looking for an industry acceptable answer here. In short, is it ok to manipulate CSS with JS. I'm learning CSS at the moment and am somewhat ok at JS right now.

Say for practice I wanted to rotate a CSS rectangle and have it hold a rotational value, say a degree up to 180. Would it be acceptable to, in some way, change or modify the CSS of that class. Or is it better practice to write, or maybe generate 182 classes for the different states it could be.

I have found that, one, you cannot change a CSS Stylesheet(without hardship), and, two, you really don't want to.

I did actually look for this, but I couldn't find anything accurate or too on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is okay do to so. Just make sure your code is well refactored and easy to read.

because: `have it hold a rotational value` is kinda complicated to define a class for each of `rotational value` (say in css) even with sass or less or other css magic.